# Send Mail Submit Action in Sitecore Forms Module

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-forms

Iam using Sitecore 9.1, I created Sitecore Form and used OFB Send Mail submit action, but when I click on Submit button I Get this Execption,

> Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
>   Message: clientApiService should not be null.
>   Parameter name: clientApiService
>   Source: Sitecore.Framework.Conditions
>      at Sitecore.Framework.Conditions.RequiresValidator`1.ThrowExceptionCore(String condition, String additionalMessage, ConstraintViolationType type)
>      at Sitecore.Framework.Conditions.Throw.ValueShouldNotBeNull[T](ConditionValidator`1 validator, String conditionDescription)
>      at Sitecore.Framework.Conditions.ValidatorExtensions.IsNotNull[T](ConditionValidator`1 validator)
>      at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd.Actions.SendEmail..ctor(IClientApiService clientApiService, ISubmitActionData submitActionData, ILogger logger, ITracker tracker)
>      at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd.Actions.SendEmail..ctor(ISubmitActionData submitActionData)

when I decompiled The DLL named "Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd.dll", The Exception returned from "Send Mail" Function.

```
public SendEmail(ISubmitActionData submitActionData)
  : this(ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IClientApiService>(), submitActionData, ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<ILogger>(), Tracker.get_Current())
{
}

public SendEmail(
  IClientApiService clientApiService,
  ISubmitActionData submitActionData,
  ILogger logger,
  ITracker tracker)
{
  base.\u002Ector(submitActionData);
  ValidatorExtensions.IsNotNull<IClientApiService>(Condition.Requires<IClientApiService>((M0) clientApiService, nameof (clientApiService)));
  ValidatorExtensions.IsNotNull<ILogger>(Condition.Requires<ILogger>((M0) logger, nameof (logger)));
  ValidatorExtensions.IsNotNull<ITracker>(Condition.Requires<ITracker>((M0) tracker, nameof (tracker)));
  this._clientApiService = clientApiService;
  this._logger = logger;
  this._tracker = tracker;
}

protected internal virtual ContactIdentifier GetContactIdentifier()
{
  Contact contact = this._tracker.get_Contact();
  ContactIdentifier contactIdentifier = contact != null ? ((IEnumerable<ContactIdentifier>) contact.get_Identifiers()).FirstOrDefault<ContactIdentifier>((Func<ContactIdentifier, bool>) (c => c.get_Type() == 2)) : (ContactIdentifier) null;
  return contactIdentifier == null ? (ContactIdentifier) null : new ContactIdentifier(contactIdentifier.get_Source(), contactIdentifier.get_Identifier(), (ContactIdentifierType) 1);
}

protected virtual bool Execute(SendEmailData data, FormSubmitContext formSubmitContext)
{
  ValidatorExtensions.IsNotNull<SendEmailData>(Condition.Requires<SendEmailData>((M0) data, nameof (data)));
  ValidatorExtensions.IsNotNull<FormSubmitContext>(Condition.Requires<FormSubmitContext>((M0) formSubmitContext, nameof (formSubmitContext)));
  if (data.MessageId == Guid.Empty)
  {
    this._logger.LogError("Empty message id");
    return false;
  }
  ContactIdentifier contactIdentifier = this.GetContactIdentifier();
  if (contactIdentifier == null)
  {
    this._logger.LogError("Contact id is null.");
    return false;
  }
  try
  {
    IClientApiService clientApiService = this._clientApiService;
    AutomatedMessage automatedMessage = new AutomatedMessage();
    automatedMessage.set_ContactIdentifier(contactIdentifier);
    automatedMessage.set_MessageId(data.MessageId);
    clientApiService.SendAutomatedMessage(automatedMessage);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    this._logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
  }
  return true;
}
```

}
}

Any Advice about this exception??

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: I did not write any code, I am using OFB submit action named "Send Mail" but when I decompiled  the DLL named "Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd.dll", The Execption returned from "Send Mail" function.

Comment: Are you using proper SMTP settings?

Comment: Can you look at this page on your site https://[Your_Site]/sitecore/admin/ShowServicesConfig.aspx? Is Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd.Services.IClientApiService, Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd listed?

Comment: yes, I tested the email connection and it is connected successfully,

Comment: @ChrisAuer i didn't find the Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd.Services.IClientApiService , how can i register it?

Comment: @ChrisAuer : i registered the dll successfuly and it logged Contact id is null.could u please advice?

Comment: It sounds like you are either missing EXM configs or you are missing the EXM license.